# Thumbnail Previewer not working for Large Images

Tags: thumbnails

I have over 500 images downloaded from Shutterstock so they are very large images, some over 10MB. Ubuntu will not show the thumbnail for anything above that file size. Is this a compiz settings issue or unity tweak, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up nautilus and go to preferences. You will get a 'preview' tab, under 'other previewable files' choose a higher file size than 10MB.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to achieve this, I have no "preferences" whitin nautilus, so go to dConf editor > org > gnome > nautilus > preferences and look for "thumbnail-limit" and change its value for a higher one. I personally chose 20971520 (that is 20 megas in bytes). Good luck!

Comment: I do not know the reason for which I do not have preferences in nautilus, I am using Manjaro, so the second solution applies for any distro.

Comment: I'm using gnome desktop manager, that might be why I dont have the preferences in nautilus. This worked for me. Thanks :)